# using HOC in some component, not every component in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

First, i have been connected componentA, componentB, componentC to redux. secondly, export componentA from BackHandlerHoc

```
import React from 'react'
import { BackHandler,Platform} from "react-native";


export default function BackHandlerHoc(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            if (Platform.OS === "android") {
                BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.goBack.bind(this));
            }
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            if (Platform.OS === "android") {
                BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.goBack.bind(this));
            }
        }


        goBack = () => {
            console.log("goBack")
            // some code
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            )
        }

    }
}
```

in componentA

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(BackHandlerHoc(componentA))
```

in componentB

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(componentB)
```

in componentC

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(componentC)
```

The problem is every component which has been connected to redux(componentB, componentC, componentA) get the BackHandler.addEventListener. 
I want just componentA get the BackHandler.addEventListener.
what have to do ?!

Comment: I don't really understand what is your problem, you want some instances of componentA not to have the event listener behavior ?

Comment: componentA takes addEventListener but not just componentA. every compenent in my project take addEventListener. that cause of using redux.